# How to move a line up with stack-like movement based on user's input using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Given a list of strings:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

User's input: Move line 4 to line 2.

So, the output is going to be:

```
a
d
b
c
e
```

How one might be able to achieve that?  Preferably using `sed`'s hold and pattern space commands.

Answer (score 3):

Moving line 4 backwards to just after line 1 is the same as moving 2 and 3 *forwards* to after line 4.

```bsh
$ sed -e '2 { h; d; }' -e '3 { H; d; }' -e '4 G' file
a
d
b
c
e
```

That is, save line 2 to the hold space. Then append all other lines that should be moved to the hold space with `H` (i.e. only line 3). At the line we want to move the range to, append the hold space with `G`.

To move line 5 to after the second line (i.e., move lines 2, 3, and 4 to after line 5), use `3,4` as the range for the second expression, and `5` in place of `4` for the last.

In general, moving line `a` to after line `b` where the movement is towards the start of the file, could be expressed as moving the lines `b+1` through to `a-1` forwards to after line `a`.

Expressed as purely moving a range of lines, `x` to `y`, forwards to after the line `z`, we could write a `sed` command to move a range of lines forwards like so:

```bsh
sed -e "$x { h; d; }" -e "$((x+1)),$y { H; d; }" -e "$z G" file
```

Example, "move lines 2 and 3 to just after line 4" (this is what the question asks about):

```bsh
$ x=2 y=3 z=4; sed -e "$x { h; d; }" -e "$((x+1)),$y { H; d; }" -e "$z G" file
a
d
b
c
e
```

Example, "move the first and second line to the end"

```bsh
$ x=1 y=2 z='$'; sed -e "$x { h; d; }" -e "$((x+1)),$y { H; d; }" -e "$z G" file
c
d
e
a
b
```

Note that we can't use this to move a *single* line forward, as the range in the second expression would be reversed and generate the wrong output. For single line ranges, the second expression must be by-passed, or we could use `$x,$y { H; $x h; d; }` to replace the first and second expression (which performs an unnecessary `H` for one line and an unnecessary line number test for all the other lines in the range we need to move, but which simplifies the expression and the logic in the script later).

In a shell script, given two line numbers, `a` (the line to move), and `b` the line to insert line `a` after, you could do something like

```bsh
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ] || [ "$a" -eq "$((b+1))" ]; then
    # No move
    set -- -e b
else

    if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]; then
        # Move forwards
        x="$a" y="$a" z="$b"
    else
        # Move backwards
        x="$((b+1))" y="$((a-1))" z="$a"
    fi

    set -- -e "$x,$y { H; $x h; d; }" -e "$z G"
fi

sed "$@" file
```

Testing:

```bsh
$ a=4 b=1 sh script
a
d
b
c
e
```

```bsh
$ a=1 b=4 sh script
b
c
d
a
e
```

---

Using the `ed` editor, this is simply done using `4m1`, i.e. "move line 4 to after line 1":

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' 4m1 ,p Q | ed -s file
a
d
b
c
e
```

"Move line 1 to after line 4":

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' 1m4 ,p Q | ed -s file
b
c
d
a
e
```

A generalization of the shell script above that moves the range `a,b` to after line `c` (i.e. what `a,b m c` does in `ed`), using `sed`:

```bsh
# Moves range a,b to after line c
# Corresponds to "a,b m c" in ed(1)

if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]; then
    # Error
    echo 'Range is reversed' >&2
    exit 1
elif [ "$c" -ge "$a" ] && [ "$c" -lt "$b" ]; then
    # Error
    echo 'Can not move range to within range' >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$b" -eq "$c" ] || [ "$a" -eq "$((c+1))" ]; then
    # No move
    set -- -e b
else

    if [ "$a" -lt "$c" ]; then
        # Move forwards
        x="$a" y="$b" z="$c"
    else
        # Move backwards
        x="$((c+1))" y="$((a-1))" z="$b"
    fi

    set -- -e "$x,$y { H; $x h; d; }" -e "$z G"

fi

sed "$@" file
```

The essential part of this script, just like of the other script presented further up in this answer, is the last inner `if` statement which sets `x`, `y`, and `z` depending on the directionality of the move.  The rest is just sanity-checking.

Comment: To move forward, it is easier to do with `sed '2{h;d}; 4{p;x}' inputfile`. Is there any easy way to do the backward?

Comment: @sngbd Is that easier than `2{h;d;}` followed by `4G` which I have in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} FNR==1{tmp=a[4]; a[4]=a[2]; a[2]=tmp} {print a[FNR]}' file file
a
d
c
b
e
```

or to swap multiple lines just populate the `swap[]` array below with the pairs of line numbers to swap:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { split("2 4 3 5",swap) }
    NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
    FNR==1 {
        for ( i=1; i in swap; i+=2 ) {
            tmp = a[swap[i]]
            a[swap[i]] = a[swap[i+1]]
            a[swap[i+1]] = tmp
        }
    }
    { print a[FNR] }
' file file
a
d
e
b
c
```

Comment: Since you're reading the whole file into memory, you might just as well use `4m2` in `ed`.

Comment: @they I haven't used `ed` in about 40 years so idk if `4m2` swaps lines or something else or if there's any caveats for it (e.g. maybe that requires you to modify the original file or make a copy of it first?) You could post that as an alternative solution.

Comment: It's already part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
### initialize variables
a=2
b=4
b1=$((b-1))
```

---

Using sed

```
sed -n ":1
  $a,$b{
    $b1!{N;b1;}
    h;n;G
  }
  p
" file
```

---

Using the Perl utility

```
perl -ne "$a..$b-1"' and push(@A,$_) or print($_,splice(@A))' file
```

---

Using awk

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '
a<=NR && NR<b {x[++i]=$0;next}
{
  print
  for (n=i; i>0; i--)
    print x[n-i+1]
}
' file
```

---

---

Using Python:

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it

ors = rs = "\n"
inp = sys.argv.pop(1)
a,b = map(int,sys.argv[1:])

chomp = lambda x: x.rstrip(rs)

with open(inp) as g:
  f = map(chomp,g)

  for nr,_ in enumerate(f,1):
    if nr < a: print(_)
    else: break

  G = list(it.islice(f,0,b-a))
  print(G.pop(),_,*G,sep=ors)

  for _ in f: print(_)

' file "$a" "$b"
```

---

Using the GNU desk calculator utility:

```
< file sed 's/.*/[&]/' |
 dc -e "[q]se
[?pc   l.1+ds. $a>p]sp
[?     l.1+ds. $b>q]sq
[LMpc  l*1-ds*  1<r]sr
[?z0=e pc      z0=?]s?
[SM z0<w]sw
[
  1s.   # initialize line counter
  lpx   # print lines before 2
  lqx   # store on stack lines 2..4
  ?zs*p # save stack size n print nxt 
  lwx   # save stack onto register 4..2
  lrx   # print register contents 2..2
  l?x   # print remaining lines
]s@
l@x
"
```